# Unique subspace that contains all vectors that are orthogonal to 2 independent vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra

It's a problem from MIT 18.06 14 Spring Exam1. The vectors are all 4 dimensional.
I suppose that there are infinitely many such space orthogonal to that fixed subspace spanned by those 2 independent vectors (let's call them **v** and **w**). But 2 dimensional subspace that contains all and only vectors orthogonal to those 2 vectors is a different thing. It's hard to visualize this problem in 4 dimensional space so I tried reasoning in 3 dimensional space. There are infinitely many 2 dimensional plane orthogonal to the subspace spanned by **z-axis**. But only the x-y plane contains all vectors orthogonal to **z-axis**. I believe it's also true for higher dimension (such space is unique).

OK, but I don't know how to extend this 3 dimensional case to 4 dimensional space to convince myself. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A vector $\mathbf{a}$ belonging to that space satisfy the two equations
$$
\mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{v}=0\\
\mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{w}=0
$$
If you have a basis, and a representation of the inner product in this basis, then that is a homogeneous linear system of two equations in four unknown (the components of $\mathbf{a}$), and the set of its solutions is a subspace of dimension $2$ (given that the two equations are independent because the two vector are independent).

Comment: Right. How could I miss that. Thank you.